# PHPUnit whitelist code coverage

Tags: php, zend-framework, phpunit, netbeans-7, whitelist

The whitelist isn't working how I would expect when get code coverage reports. I am using Zend Framework and my Zend files are also in the library directory just like the project quickstart.

I'm running PHPUnit 3.6 from Netbeans 7.0.1

I only really want to see the coverage for the classes for `MyLib`.

```
<whitelist>
    <directory suffix=".php">../../library/MyLib</directory>
</whitelist>
```

But in the report I seem to get a percentage value for several Zend files eg. `Zend_Controller_Front`, `Zend_Loader_Autoloader` etc.

Obviously I haven't written any tests for these classes and it is no surprise that I have 0% coverage.

What have I missed?

Comment: What is your blacklist? Are you using `addUncoveredFilesFromWhitelist="true"`? And which PHPUnit version are you using?

Comment: I'm using PHPUnit 3.6, I've tried a blacklist as well but get the same result. Just tried "addUncoveredFilesFromWhitelist" true and false, but still getting Zend coverage

Comment: Just seeing, please use absolute paths in your XML file and/or ensure those are correctly resolved by using a step-debugger for your phpunit test-runner call (which I think is hard to do in Netbeans). Also ensure that your XML file is loaded.

Comment: Yes, just noticed that my paths were incorrect and now it's working

Comment: I added it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use absolute paths in your XML file and/or ensure those are correctly resolved by your phpunit test-runner call. Also ensure that your XML file is loaded.

Comment: Just to note/make it clear: Relative paths work when used correctly and should be preferred over absolute ones so that the xml file is portable. Good debugging step though

Comment: With respect this answer is old, it seems incomplete. What is `test-runner` and how did it help solve the problem?